# Make div cover entire row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this table below. When I click on a row a div is displayed:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyjYqM
The problem is the div is displayed in a cell, and I want it to be displayed on the entire row. I have tried using this CSS properties but the result is not what I wanted:

```
#endDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The result: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djReog

Any ideas? I want the div to be displayed like an accordion when i click a specific row

Comment: I do not understand your question. What excactly would you like to achieve? Would you like the form to be displayed as a row? Then change it's html structure to fit the table and inert it after clicked row.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski This table contains a list of nodes. Each row represents a node. When I click on a specific row, this #endDiv div (containing more info about the node) opens. What I want is to display this entire div as a row(like an accordion). I’ve tried to make it a td and add the colspan=“6” property but without succes

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBWxEo)?

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski something like this. but I want the content to be displayed as a list (your example displays each data in different cell)

Comment: Or this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XVdVmg

Comment: I want it like here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyjYqM but displayed on entire row (in this example it's displayed in the first cell, enlarging it)

Comment: I would suggest adding somewhere a colspan, I'll look into it to where it should be added :)

Comment: [Here you go](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpXRgz)

Comment: @mecnism Try this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBgzdX). I have just changed your `div having id #endDiv` to `tr and td having colspan=6`. Also, I add some `CSS` for `li`. Hope you wish this thing with your code.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski thank you man! that’s exactly what i wanted!

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal thanks for the ideea. It worked finally with KrzysztofJaniszewski ‘s example

Comment: It's my pleasure. @mecnism

Answer (score 1):

Tables or tbody in this case should not have div elements inside, as it is bad practice.

Try making the div `id="endDiv"` into an actual TR instead of display: table-row;
Then make the inside td have `colspan="6"`